# Error occurred while getting the APIs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I locally installed WSO2 API manager and create API but API list is not coming at WSO2 dashboard . It displaying an error i.e

```
[2015-11-03 18:47:29,781] ERROR - AsyncDataPublisher Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7614"
index:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while getting the APIs
```

[image]
Version of API manager is 1.9.1

I can't get  any API statistics 
[image]

Comment: What's the API Manager version?

Comment: <Version>1.9.1</Version>

Comment: Are you using some other product with API Manager?

Comment: This API Manager was running well , But when I installed BAM , it display this type of error.
Now I stop BAM service , but same error occurred .

Comment: When there was no BAM service , I can't got the particular section where we put data for calling API at api store

Comment: I stop both  BAM service and API Manager , then 1st start BAM & then API Manager  service I can't access API Manager Publisher  , it display error
"HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL"
My BAM version is 2.5

Comment: Was this the only error trace you have in API Manager?

Comment: yes...
I have only  error in API Manager..

I solved one problem now BAM service and API Manager both running at a time..

But current problem is  API list is not coming at API Manager Dashboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94159/discussion-between-arif-and-abimaran-kugathasan).

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be occurred when you have not configured  information according to the Port Offset value. As an example if the port offset value of BAM instance is 3,need to configure as follows in  property in the api-manager.xml which is in /repository/conf/ folder.

```
    <ThriftPort>7614</ThriftPort>
    <BAMServerURL>{tcp://<IP Address>:7614/}</BAMServerURL>
```

Also make sure to restart both servers.